# App.Current.MainPage NullReferenceException in Constructor of MainPageModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

On the loading of `MainPage`, I am pushing another page from Constructor of `MainPageModel`. It throws `NullReferenceException` in `MainPageModel`. This is my code

**`MainPage` constructor**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Title = "MainPage";
    BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel(); 
}
```

**`MainPageModel` constructor**

```
public MainPageViewModel()
{
    App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage()); //Exception
    //CommandMenu1 = new Command(async () => await NavigateNext());
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think `App.Current.MainPage` is null while initially building the `MainPage`.

Answer (score 5):

What probably happens is this:

```
public class App
{
    MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

The `MainPage()` constructor has to be completed before it is assigned to the `MainPage` property of your `App`. Therefore, trying to access the `App.Current.MainPage` before then, you will get a `NullReferenceException`. This means you will have to find another way to achieve what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I am using basic Mvvm for MasterDetailPage. Literally I want to do is `(App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());` from MainPageModel. From MainPage constructor I am able to do so, But this I want to shift to Mvvm. Is there any way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access MainPage in your View Model before it has been fully initialized. Instead of binding in your MainPage constructor bind in `App.xaml.cs`

```
public App() {
   InitializeComponent();

   MainPage = new MainPage();
   MainPage.BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnAppearing()` instead of `MainPageViewModel()` to give it time to load fully, 
Code :

```
 protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewPage());
```

on New Page.Cs

```
InitializeComponent();
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
```