# Xamarin.Forms: Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert() throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using `Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert` from a separate class and I'm getting this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
}
```

**MainPage.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private static readonly DisplayMessage DisplayMessage = new();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DisplayMessage.Display();
    }
}
```

**DisplayMessage.cs**

```cs
public class DisplayMessage
{
    public async void Display()
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Hello World", "Welcome", "OK");
    }
}
```

I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883887/application-current-pagename-returns-null) proposing this solution but it doesn't help

```cs
public static Page RootPage;

public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    MainPage = new MainPage();
    
    App.RootPage = this.MainPage;
}
    
App.RootPage.DisplayAlert(title, message, ok);
```

Does someone have a direction to find out ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don’t call this from the page constructor

Comment: You cannot do that in the constructor, the `MainPage` object only exists after construction has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access the `MainPage` instance before it has finished construction.

Instead of doing this:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private static readonly DisplayMessage DisplayMessage = new();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DisplayMessage.Display();
    }
}
```

You can do the following, which should work:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private static readonly DisplayMessage DisplayMessage = new();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ShowMessage()
    {
        DisplayMessage.Display();
    }
}
```

Then, after construction finished, the `ShowMessage()` method can be called, which in turn will display the message.

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage();

        MainPage.ShowMessage();
    }
}
```

Now, the overall design of your code is debatable, but making these changes should lead to a usable solution.

**Update:**

You may also want to add a null-check to the following piece of code:

```cs
public class DisplayMessage
{
    public async void Display()
    {
        //note the "?"
        await Application.Current.MainPage?.DisplayAlert("Hello World", "Welcome", "OK");
    }
}
```

Note the `?` which serves to ensure that `DisplayAlert()` only gets called when `MainPage` is set to an instance.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your advice :)

Answer (score 3):

What is the need of so much code for just an alert ?

To make sure that the alert is shown after the page is loaded we can just call the alert code in a `Loaded` event handler, e.g. like this:

**MainPage.xaml:**

```xml
<ContentPage
    Loaded="AfterContentPageLoaded">
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```cs
private void AfterContentPageLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.MainPage?.DisplayAlert("Hello", "It was So Simple", "OK");
}
```

You can also pass your method from your *DisplayMessage.cs* class into `Loaded` event handler on *MainPage.xaml.cs* page.

❤️

Comment: That's a very direct approach using an event, which is fine if that's the only time or place when a message is supped to be displayed. The OP uses a generic approach with a `DisplayMessage` class, though, and the problem there was that it tried to access an instance of `MainPage` before it was constructed, which led to an exception. I agree that in most cases a simple solution suffices (using Occam's Razor).